# Unable to add marker on the map using leaflet R

Tags: r, postgresql, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a simple problem in this R code:

```
main_visualization <- function(){
  library(leaflet)
  library(RPostgreSQL)

  # Get a database connection
  con <- connectDB()

  # Reading the required table from the database to company dataframe
  c_df <- dbReadTable(con, "custom_ways_filtered")  
  dbDisconnect(con)

  c_df <- c_df[c("tags","latitude","longitude")]

  c_longitude <- as.numeric(c_df$longitude)
  c_latitude <- as.numeric(c_df$latitude)

  leaflet(data = c_df) %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 4) %>%
    addMarkers(~c_longitude, ~c_latitude, popup = ~as.character(c_df$tags))

}#END of main_visualization()
```

I am reading a table from a postgresql database. The table contains OSM information about buildings and I have checked that I am getting everything in the R code as I need to retrieve from the database. Then I am **using Leaflet API to show markers** on top of the map. In order to do this I am getting lat/lon from the dataframe that has retrieved data from the postgres table. But Instead of getting the markers on the map, I am getting **nothing at all**. The size of the dataframe is **1624** instances.

Kindly help me in figuring out the problem. I have been following [this](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) Leaflet blog. I have also searched on few other blogs but cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Thank you very much for your time and looking forward for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
c_df$c_longitude <- as.numeric(c_df$longitude)
c_df$c_latitude  <- as.numeric(c_df$latitude)
```

einar